# Is the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the map $\Vert \cdot \Vert _{C^k}$ a $\mathbb{C}$-Banach space?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

Below $(l^\infty_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R}^n),\Vert \cdot \Vert _\infty)$ denote the $\mathbb{C}$-Banach space of bounded functions $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ where $\Vert f\Vert _\infty:=\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|f(x)|$.

Let $k\in \mathbb{N}_0\cup\{\infty\}$ and consider the set:

$$C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n):=\big\{f\in C^k_\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R}^n):f\text{ is }2\pi\text{-periodic}\big\}.$$

Considering the [multi-index notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-index_notation), we can prove that if $f\in C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $\partial ^\alpha (f)\in l^\infty _\mathbb{C}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ satisfying $|\alpha|\leq k$. Knowing that we can conclude that the map $\Vert \cdot \Vert _{C^k}:C^k_\text{per}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to \mathbb{R}$ given by $\Vert f\Vert _{C^k}:=\sum_{|\alpha |\leq k}\Vert \partial ^\alpha (f )\Vert _\infty $ is well-defined.

**My question is:** is the $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ with the map $\Vert \cdot \Vert _{C^k}$ a $\mathbb{C}$-Banach space? If so, how do I prove it?

Thank you for your attention!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definition of the norm in $C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$ seems to require that $k<\infty$, so I will make that assumption.

The answer is yes.  Let us begin with an auxiliary result:

**Lemma**.  Let $\{f_n\}_n$ be a sequence in $C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ converging pointwise to some function $f$, and such
that, for a given $k$, the sequence $\{\partial f_n/\partial x_k\}_n$ converges uniformly over compact sets to a
function $g$.  Then $\partial f/\partial x_k=g$.

*Proof*.  For every $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, and every $t\in \mathbb R$, we have
$$
  f(x+te_k) -   f(x) =
  \lim_{n\to\infty} f_n(x+te_k) -   f_n(x) = $$$$ =
  \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^t \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_k}(x+se_k)\, ds =
  \int_0^t g(x+se_k)\, ds.
  $$
The conclusion follows by taking the derivative relative to $t$ of the above.  QED

This said, suppose that $\{f_n\}_n$ is a Cauchy sequence in $C_{\text{per}}^k(\mathbb{R}^n)$.  Then, for every
$\alpha\in\mathbb{N}_0^n$ with $|\alpha|\leq k$, we have that
$$
  \|\partial^\alpha f_n -  \partial^\alpha f_m\|_\infty  \leq    \|f_n - f_m\|_{C^k},
  $$
so the sequence $\{\partial^\alpha f_n\}_n$ is  Cauchy  in the Banach space
$l^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and hence  it converges uniformly to some $g_\alpha $ in that space.

Setting $f=g_{(0,0,\ldots ,0)}$, we may use the Lemma and  induction on $|\alpha |$ to prove that $\partial^\alpha f=g_\alpha $, whenever $|\alpha|\leq k$, so we conclude
that $f_n\to f$ relative to $\Vert \cdot \Vert_{C^k}$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.  The same argument above holds on any compact manifold, which is essentially what you have due to periodicity.